# Symfony 3 - Weird data return from Repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've got Repository method which returns sum of missing invoices price to pay

```
public function getAmountToPay()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('c.name, (i.price - COALESCE(sum(p.amount), 0)) as price')
        ->leftJoin('i.payments', 'p')
        ->join('i.company', 'c')
        ->where('i.dueDate > :now')
        ->groupBy('i.id')
        ->having('sum(i.price) > SUM(p.amount) OR SUM(p.amount) IS NULL ')
        ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime())
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Pure SQL returns normal rows but if I do it in doctrine, it returns some weird data in array with 0 values:

```
"afterDeadline" => array:3 [▼
0 => array:2 [▼
  "name" => "Example company #1"
  "price" => "0"
]
1 => array:2 [▼
  "name" => "Example company #2"
  "price" => "0"
]
2 => array:2 [▼
  "name" => "Example company #1"
  "price" => "117.99000000000001"
]
```

Why it has companies with 0 value? Only the last array index is ok.

Comment: you have the sql COALESCE , if the result of the sum is null you get 0 from COALESCE

Comment: Ohh, right. I didn't see that. Is there any way to keep that COALESCE and have only companies with values more than 0?

Comment: you add another where clause

Comment: I cannot write WHERE clause 'cuz of SUM but if I do HAVING clause it says  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i1_.price' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the solution which [madalinivascu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4613398/madalin-ivascu) suggested. It will look like similar to this:

```
public function getAmountToPay()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('c.name, (i.price - COALESCE(sum(p.amount), 0)) as price')
        ->leftJoin('i.payments', 'p')
        ->join('i.company', 'c')
        ->where('i.dueDate > :now')
        ->andWhere('i.price != 0')
        ->groupBy('i.id')
        ->having('sum(i.price) > SUM(p.amount) OR SUM(p.amount) IS NULL ')
        ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime())
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```